# Detect cell change in one column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` to detect changes to the worksheet, but I only want to detect changes to column A.

Is it possible to restrict the detection to just that range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code. Note that it will only be triggered by manually changing cells in column `A`. Changes triggered by calculations won't be captured.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
       'your code
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't work when cell changes automatically.